# Как в Java из строки сделать список чисел?

Tags: java, строки, список

Есть строка с цифрами от 0 до 9, без пробелов. На выходе должен получиться список int, при чем если после какой-то единицы стоит ноль, то такие ноль и единица должны быть записаны в списке как 10. Таким образом не выходе должен получиться список из чисел от 1 до 10. Как это сделать?

Comment: Как вы пытались эту задачу решить? Что именно у вас не получилось?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Извлечение чисел от 0 до 10 из потока циферь.
Главное сформулировать условие, когда заканчивается одно число и начинается другое.
Если на предыдущей итерации получена единица и сейчас перед нами ноль, то мы всё ещё находимся на том же самом числе (на десятке). В остальных случаях мы перешли на следующее число.
Когда случился переход на следующее число, предыдущее надо вывести (поместить в массив)

```
// чтобы просто переводить символы в числа/цифры
public static Map<Character, Integer> CHAR2DIGIT = new HashMap<Character, Integer>() {{
    put('0', 0);
    put('1', 1);
    put('2', 2);
    put('3', 3);
    put('4', 4);
    put('5', 5);
    put('6', 6);
    put('7', 7);
    put('8', 8);
    put('9', 9);
}};

public static List<Integer> numbers(String input) {
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    int number = -1; // сюда будем собирать очередное число. -1 когда находимся в самом начале потока и ещё не получено ни одной цифры
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        int digit = CHAR2DIGIT.get(input.charAt(i)); // очередная цифра

        if (digit != 0 || number != 1) { // условие перехода на следующее число
            if (number > -1) numbers.add(number); // вывод предыдущего
            number = 0; // сброс для расчёта нового числа
        }

        number = number * 10 + digit; // незамысловатая формула для сбора числа из его циферь
    }
    if (number > -1) numbers.add(number); // не забыть вывести последнее число после цикла

    return numbers;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (Integer n : numbers("1234567891001")) {
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

По вашим условиям '0' тоже должен присутствовать (когда '0' в начале строки или не после '1'), то есть диапазон не от 1 до 10, а от 0 до 10:

```
    String str = "010320101";
    int[] numbers = str.replaceAll("10", ":").chars().map(i -> i -= 48).toArray();
```

Результат:

```
    numbers[i]:
    0 = 0
    1 = 10
    2 = 3
    3 = 2
    4 = 0
    5 = 10
    6 = 1
```

**Дополнение**: "должен получиться *список*"

```
List<Integer> numbers = str.replaceAll("10", ":").chars().mapToObj(i -> i -= 48)
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать с использованием Java 8 Stream API:

```
    public void someMethod(){
    String str = "1234567890";
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(str.split("")).map(s -> Integer.valueOf(s)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    list.replaceAll(i -> i==0?10:i);
    list.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: Сдаётся мне, что вместо 0 будет получаться 10, вместо 10 - 110

Comment: Sergey, так ведь и должно так получаться, судя по описанию задачи)

Comment: @Dershov, исправил.